# Two steps in proof of the uniqueness of the total derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
In page 16 of [Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds](http://www.strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/spivak-calc-manifolds.pdf), he proves the uniqueness of the total derivative as follows:

Suppose $f: \R^n \to \R^m$ is differentiable at $a \in \R^n$ with derivatives the linear maps $\lambda, \mu: \R^n \to \R^m$. Let $d(h) = f(a + h) - f(a)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\color{green}{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{|\lambda(h)- \mu(h)|}{|h|} &= \color{green}{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{|\lambda(h) - d(h) + d(h) - \mu(h)|}{|h|} \\ &\leq \color{green}{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{|\lambda(h) - d(h)|}{|h|} + \color{green}{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{|d(h) - \mu(h)|}{|h|} \\ &= 0.
\end{align*}

Now for $0 \neq x \in \R^n$, the sequence $tx \to 0$ as $t \to 0$, so
$$ 0 \color{red}{=} \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{|\lambda(tx) - \mu(tx)|}{|tx|} = \frac{|\lambda(x) - \mu(x)|}{|x|} ,$$
and thus $\lambda(x) = \mu(x)$.

**My question is**: how do we know the original limit exists? I suspect that the more general fact holds that if $f$ is a linear map then $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(h)|}{|h|}$ exists, but I am not sure how to prove it.

**I also would like to know why equality above in red holds.** I assume it has to do with the fact that
$$g \text{ continuous at h} \Longleftrightarrow \left( \forall (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = h \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} g(a_n) = g(h)  \right) ,$$
where $g: \R^n \to \R$ (the function inside the original limit) is defined by
$$ g(h) := \frac{|\lambda(h) - \mu(h)|}{|h|} ,$$
and $a_n \to 0$ is the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n} x$. But why can we use this fact when $g$ is not continuous at $0$?

**EDIT #1:**

For my second question, I see that the following fact would answer my question:

$$\lim_{h \to c} g(h) = d \Longleftrightarrow \left( \forall (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = c \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} g(a_n) = d  \right) ,$$

but I am not sure if it is true as I have never came across it. However, I have come across the weaker version of the above fact when $d = g(c)$ (in which case $g$ is continuous at $c$), which I know to be true.

**EDIT #2:**
On my first question, if $f: \R^n  \to \R^m$ is a linear map, and
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(h)|}{|h|} $$
exists, if we denote the function on the inside by
$$ f^*(h) := \frac{|f(h)|}{|h|} ,$$
it is true that $f^*(\lambda h) = \lambda f^*(h)$ for $\lambda \in \R$, hence $f^*$ is constant along any line passing through the origin. But since the limits along any of these lines must be the same, $f^*$ must be a constant map <s>and hence the zero map. I guess this confirms with what was found originally, but we can't reason that
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|\lambda(h) - \mu(h)|}{|h|} $$
exists *because it is the zero map*, as that is what we are trying to prove!</s>

**EDIT #3**:
I believe EDIT #1 answers my second question, as I have now found a source which proves the fact discussed there.

Some of my reasoning towards the end of EDIT #2, so it has been marked out.

Also, I just realized that if we replace all occurrences of $\lim$ (only the ones marked in green way above) with $\liminf$ or $\limsup$, the same manipulations hold, and this time we know the existence of each quantity is guaranteed, so we would have
$$ \liminf = \limsup = 0 \implies \lim = 0 .$$
Does anyone know if it was an error on Spivak's part to not present the proof this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are right, strictly speaking. But it is easier IMO to use `sandwich rule' then talk about liminfs/limsups.

$$ 0\le \frac{|\lambda(h) - \mu(h)|}{|h|} \le \frac{|\lambda(h) - d(h)|}{|h|} + \frac{|\mu(h) - d(h)|}{|h|}  \xrightarrow[h\to 0]{} 0$$
hence $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|\lambda(h) - \mu(h)|}{|h|}$ (exists and) equals $0$. In any case, I suspect that Spivak expects a reader of this book to be happy to make this sort of reasoning rigourous themselves.

As for the second issue it's not exactly sequences but paths, so you'd want something like
$$\lim_{h\to 0}f(h) =  0 \iff \forall g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n \text{ with } \lim_{t\to 0} g(t) = 0, \ \lim_{t\to 0}f(g(t)) = 0.$$
(you can fuss about details e.g. f should be defined on an open neighbourhood of zero...) And to prove this you can just slowly write out epsilons and deltas. E.g. proof of "$LHS\implies RHS$": Let $\epsilon>0$ and fix any such $g$. By assumption, there is $\delta_1>0$ such that $|f(h)|<\epsilon$ for all $|h|<\delta_1$. As $g(t) \to 0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $|g(t)|<\delta_1$ for all $|t|<\delta$. Result follows. For the other way round you might want to try to prove the contrapositive statement.

Comment: Thank your for answering my questions. Regarding paths/sequences, my argument involving the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n} x$ still works, right? Admittedly it is more awkward this way, but it works out by invoking the fact I discussed in my second edit? I was not aware of limits being preserved along paths, though, thank you for introducing this fact to me.

Comment: @AbcedDecba Well in this case the sequence is in fact enough for uniqueness, but it would not follow from one sequence limit existing that the limit $t\to 0$ exists!

Comment: Right, but my point is that after establishing the limit (first one marked in green) exists (using either limsup/liminf or the sandwich rule like you described), then the limit along all sequences (and paths) will be the same, so my original argument is (awkward but) correct? Sorry if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, that's right :)

Comment: Great, thanks .

Comment: This is slightly unrelated, but would you happen to know if the fact about paths you highlight can be used to prove my fact about sequences through some sort of "discretization" (at least the forward direction)? It really does feel like it should be the case that every convergent sequence (seen as a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^n$) can be "extended" to some appropriate function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Also, I'd like to mention that the forward direction of the fact about paths is a special case of this more general fact about composition: if $f, g$ are real functions and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ are such that $g$ is continuous at $b$ and
$$ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = b  ,$$
$$ \lim_{x \to b} g(y) = c ,$$ 
then we have
$$ \lim_{x \to a} (f \circ g)(x) = c .$$
Of course this can be generalized to more than one dimension, I just write it like this for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @AbcedDecba they are both equivalent characterisations of a limit, yes. I only mentioned paths because that's what Spivak uses